# How to navigate to a normal ContentPage in fullscreen from NavigationPage with TabbedPage?

Tags: xamarin, navigation, tabbedpage

There is [a Xamarin official sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage) that demonstrates how to use TabbedPage with NavigationPage together. The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, when it navigates to a sub-page, the sub-page is "nested" in the TabbedPage. I want to know how can I make the sub-page in fullscreen, which means when it's on the sub-page, it takes up the whole screen and the TabbedPage doesn't show. Below is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you have to embed your tabbed page into a navigation page.

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourTabbedPage());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Microsoft clearly states that "TabbedPage should be the root page in your application. Don't nest a TabbedPage inside another page.". See the warning in this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-multi-page-xamarin-forms-apps-with-stack-and-tab-navigation/5-implement-tab-navigation Is there another way to implement this?

Comment: Well, if you want to show/hide the tab bar Xamarin forms does not support this functionality , so you have to create a custom renderer of the tabbar and show and hide there.